# Closed subspace of a Normed Space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $W$ be a closed subspace of a Normed Space $X$. Let $x\in X $and $x\notin W$ , then $Span[{x}]\oplus W$ is a closed  ?

Any proof? 
Thanks!

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Any efforts?${}$

Comment: I was trying using sequences but I can not prove it at all

Answer (score 1):

Hints: suppose $a_nx+w_n \to z$ where $w_n \in W$ for all $n$. If $|a_n| \to \infty$ then $x+\frac 1 {a_n} w_n \to 0$ so $\frac 1 {a_n} w_n \to -x$ which gives the contradiction  that $x \in W$. In the contrary case some subsequence of $a_n$ converges to a finite limit. Now try to complete the proof.